# I am trying to up the frequency everytime button is press by 100 Hz, I am using the Input pull registor

Tags: arduino-uno

The frequency should be increased by 100 Hz whenever an external push-button on UNO digital pin 5 is depressed and then released. I think I might missing something critical.

```
#define LEDPIN 3
float highTime;
float lowTime;
int freq;
float period; 

//uint16_t val2= pulseIn(4, HIGH);
      
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) { digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN)); }
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
// initialize Timer1 (the 16-bit timer) using channel A output compare

TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
TCNT1 = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
// set compare match register for 100 Hz increments
OCR1A = 9999; // = 16000000 / (8 * 100) - 1 (must be <65536)
// turn on CTC mode
TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
// Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 8 prescaler
 TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);

// enable timer compare interrupt
TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
sei(); // allow interrupts
interrupts(); // enable global interrupts:
}
void loop() {

highTime =(pulseIn(4, HIGH));
lowTime=(pulseIn(4, LOW));
period = highTime+lowTime;
freq=1000000/period;       //getting frequency with totalTime is in Micro seconds
Serial.print(freq);
delay(1000);


Serial.print("\n");
```

Basically I want to turn the above code which display "100" in serial monitor with raises the frequency by 100 by a button press.

```
#define LEDPIN 3
const int buttonPin = 5;    // the number of the pushbutton pin

//uint16_t val2= pulseIn(4, HIGH);
// Variables will change:
int ledState = HIGH;         // the current state of the output pin
int buttonState;             // the current reading from the input pin
int lastButtonState = LOW;   // the previous reading from the input pin

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) { digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN)); }
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // initialize Timer1 (the 16-bit timer) using channel A output compare

  TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1 = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 100 Hz increments
  OCR1A = 9999; // = 16000000 / (8 * 100) - 1 (must be <65536)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 8 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);

  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
  sei(); // allow interrupts
  interrupts(); // enable global interrupts:

}
void loop() {
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);
   // If the switch changed, due to noise or pressing:
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer than the debounce
    // delay, so take it as the actual current state:

    // if the button state has changed:
    if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;

      // only toggle the LED if the new button state is HIGH
      if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        ledState = !ledState;
      }
    }
    lastButtonState = reading;

    Serial.print(reading);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("\n");

  }
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain what happens instead of the 100Hz frequency increase you seem to be expecting. One issue is already very obvious to me: There's nothing in your `loop()` that changes the frequency. Just some debounce code and something that changes the variable called `ledState` (but nothing that actually changes the state of the LED). Where did you get this code from?

Comment: I suggest using the `Bounce2` library for the button presses. It makes the handling way easier and does all the debouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Your button input pin is set to INPUT_PULLUP mode so that pin will always read HIGH unless you ground it. Your button should connect the pin to ground when it is pressed.

If you do that, then the pin will read HIGH when the button is not pressed, and LOW when the button is pressed. Near the bottom of your loop() function, you test the button and toggle the LED with:

```
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      ledState = !ledState;
  }
```

But this toggles the LED when the button is released. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: Basically, I want it I want frequency to be increased by 100 each time I press a button

Comment: I see two sketches in your question. I was looking at the second one. How are the two related, and which one are you trying to debug?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, basically I have to combine and edit 1st code with the button debounce code from the library function. The first code is just displays "100" hz and the second code I have use my first code to up 100 hz each time a button is pressed.

Comment: Then I believe you want to use the second code, but reverse the buttonState test - test it for LOW instead. Inside the 'if' block, where you toggle the LED, is where to put the code that increases the frequency.

Comment: I am still new to this. Can you please explain piece by piece what I need to change?

Comment: What you need to change? Take a new/clean Arduino project and first reliably read the button press. Then, you use the "tone()" function instead of manually setting registers. Build it yourself (based on examples), so you understand why/what code is there instead of copying it from the internet.

Comment: I does really seem like you're trying to learn to do too many things at once. Learn to manage the button until you're satisfied you've got it right and understand it. Then do the same thing with frequency - learn to set or change it in steps, maybe 1 second apart, using delay() to measure the 1 second. Then apply what you know to a sketch that watches the button and changes the frequency, both jobs using code you've already written (without the delay(), of course). It's much easier to learn the pieces one by one before you start putting them together.